# Find what numbers were pressed to get the word (opposite of phone number digit problem)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given this dictionary:

```
const DIGIT_TO_LETTERS = {
  1: [],
  2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  3: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  4: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  5: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  6: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
  7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'],
  8: ['t', 'u', 'v'],
  9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
}
```

Find what numbers were pressed to get the word `'mad'`.

I can't seem to find a solution that isn't n^2 (looping through each array and looking for the letter).

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please may you show us your attempts so far?

Comment: Create a map with letter to digit. The opposite of what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the letters and their numbers and convert by looking for a certain letter.

```js
const
    DIGIT_TO_LETTERS = { 1: [], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3: ['d', 'e', 'f'], 4: ['g', 'h', 'i'], 5: ['j', 'k', 'l'], 6: ['m', 'n', 'o'], 7: ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], 8: ['t', 'u', 'v'], 9: ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'] },
    LETTERS_TO_DIGITS = Object
        .entries(DIGIT_TO_LETTERS)
        .reduce((r, [v, letters]) => {
            letters.forEach(l => r[l] = +v);
            return r;
        }, {}),
    convert = string => Array.from(string, l => LETTERS_TO_DIGITS[l]);

console.log(convert('mad'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think this makes sense. Is the time complexity not n^2 because the looping is through two different structures (the reduce and forEach)?

Comment: if the first loop is dome, you never need to loop again, only for getting a new string.

Comment: Ah right, because the dictionary is given and not variable